# How to write variable values in a file in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sendmail

I have a stored procedure for sending email. I want to write the value of the variable `@corps` in a file and send it as file attachment. Here the code:

```
    Declare @Corps as nvarchar(max) = '<br>';
    SET @Corps = @Corps + '<a name="new"><FONT face="Arial" size="2"><b><U>Création d''Acte Rem rémunérable </b></U></FONT></a><br><br>'
                SET @corps = @corps +'<table>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<tr>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="30%">Code Acte Rem</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="13%">Unite</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="7%">Valeur</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="7%">Taux de Marge</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="7%">CAMarketing</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="18%">Commentaire</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '<th width="18%">FamilleKPI</th>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '</tr>'
                SET @corps = @corps + '</tr>'
                SET @corps = @corps + ( SELECT td1 AS td, td2 AS td, td3 AS td, td4 AS td, td5 AS td, td6 AS td, td7 AS td
                                        FROM #MyMail
                                        FOR XML RAW('tr'), ELEMENTS)
                SET @corps = @corps + '</table><br><br>';

IF @send=1
        BEGIN
            if @lst_desti is not null or @lst_desti <> ''
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                @profile_name = 'Group',
                @body_format = 'HTML',
                @recipients = @lst_desti,
                @copy_recipients = @lst_copy,
                @from_address = @expemail,
                @body = @Corps,
                @subject = @Objet,
                @importance = @Level,
                @file_attachments='C:\Users\visualisation.html';
        END
```

Is there a method to pass a variable's value to a file inside the procedure itself?

Comment: First, this is a terrible idea, SQL Server is totally the wrong place to be sending emails. Queue them up and have a service process them. However if you are determined to follow through you need to write the file to disk e.g. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2019/08/04/how-to-write-in-text-file-from-t-sql-in-sql-server-interview-question-of-the-week-236/

Answer (score 0):

To return your results as a file attachment you need to include `@attach_query_result_as_file = 1` and, for the file name you need `@query_attachment_filename   = '<file name>'`. For reasons I don't fully understand you also need to include the header as well: `@query_result_header = 1`.

This is an example of something I needed to email out this week. @SQLOUT is a variable I use to create my Dynamic SQL statement that creates the SQL/HTML output:

```
DECLARE @Corps VARCHAR(MAX) = '<your query>';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##test;
CREATE TABLE ##test (sqlout NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT ##test(sqlout) EXEC (@Corps);

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @profile_name                = '<YOUR EMAIL PROFILE',
  @recipients                  = 'Burstein@cool.com',
  @copy_recipients             = NULL,
  @subject                     = 'Test Email',
  @body                        = 'See attached',
  @body_format                 = 'HTML',
  @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
  @query_attachment_filename   = 'Test.html',
  @query                       = 'SELECT sqlout FROM ##test',
  @exclude_query_output        = 0,
  @query_no_truncate           = 1,
  @query_result_header         = 1;
```

The results of @Corps is added to a single column in my ##test table. The `@query` values is the query to retrieve the HTML. Using the parameters above you should be able to send the results as an HTML file.